# What about the reducible fibers of a surjective morphism?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

If i have a surjective morphism $\phi :S \rightarrow C$, where $S$ is a smooth complex algebraic projective surface and $C$ a smooth projective curve, what can i say about the number of the fibers of $\phi$?
is it true that  the set of reducible fibers of $\phi$ is finite?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not true as written. For example, suppose you have a surjective morphism $S \rightarrow \Gamma$ with $\Gamma$ a curve, and then $\Gamma \rightarrow C$ a nontrivial finite morphism of curves. Then almost all fibres of the composite morphism $\phi: S \rightarrow C$ will be disconnected, in particular reducible.

On the other hand, if $\phi$ has connected fibres, then this is true. See Shafarevich II.6.1, Theorem 1 ("First Bertini Theorem"). That says that if $S$ and $C$ are irreducible and $\phi$ has connected fibres, then there is a dense open set $U \subset C$ such that $\phi^{-1}(p)$ is irreducible for all $p \in U$. Then $C \setminus U$ is a finite set of points, which is exactly what you want.

Comment: and, for example, in general is not true that a sujective  morphism between a complex algebraic surface and a curve has connected fibers?

Comment: @dario: no. That's exactly what the example in my first paragraph is showing ("almost all fibres...will be disconnected").

Comment: this question rise from the lecture of a theorem. First there is another hypothesis that is there exist a point $x \in C$ such that $\phi^{-1}(x) = \mathbb{P}^1$. During the proof i see that the reducible fibers of $\phi$ are finite. So i don't know the reason. Is the last condition enough to say thet $\phi$ has connected fibers?

Comment: @dario: If --- as in your hypothesis --- one fibre is connected, and $C$ is a *smooth* curve, then yes, all fibres must be connected. I don't know a reference for that right now, but it should be in the standard books.

Comment: thanks. now i try to find some reference

Comment: I know that a fiber is a sub-variety of $S$ but can i tell something about the dimension of it?

Comment: @dario: if $X \rightarrow Y$ is a surjective morphism, almost all fibres will have dimension $dim \ X - dim \ Y$. See Shafarevich Ch. 1.